# error message after checkout a new branch

Tags: git, github

I run the git checkout command for a given branch in the code repo

```
/util/bin/git checkout experimental-branch
```

I got the following error message, what does it mean, and how to address this kind of issue.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        tests/test_plan.py
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is saying that, you need to commit the changes before switching the branches
do this,
`git add.`
`git commit -m "your message here"`

hope this will help you.
happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Before switching branches you have to commit the existing changes or stash them or even you can reset them.

> To commit you can follow these steps

```
git add .
git commit -m "Your commit message"
```

> To Stash

```
git stash
```

> To reset

```
git reset --hard
```